# Preventing fb.ui() from scrolling the browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I'm working on a Facebook canvas page application using an iframe.  I'm using fb.ui() to create a dialog box for sharing however when the dialog opens, it's centered at first, then once the async call loads the dialog, it moves the dialog box to the top of the iframe and scrolls the browser to the top.

I considered using jQuery to reposition the box however I'd also have to scroll the browser position which screams hack to me.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has been reported as a [bug in Facebook's SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/359862544085722/). I'm not optimistic, but maybe if everyone says they can reproduce it, they'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, positioning in iFrames sucks.  The easiest way to keep the dialog positioned correctly is to use the popup display option which pops a new browser window above the center of the current page.  It's not as pretty, but it works nicely.

```
//generic sharing function
var fbshare = function(url, display) {
    var share = {
        method: 'stream.share',
        u: url,
        display: display
    };
    FB.ui(share);
};

//share using popup
<a href="#fbshare" onClick="fbshare('http://www.theurl.com','popup');">Share</a>
```

Comment: Popup does work.. but people with popup blockers would not be able to see this. :(

Comment: @eNetik, somehow these popups aren't blocked, at least not in FF or Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery to get the scroll position, and then setting it in the response function.

```
scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
FB.ui(
{
//setup
},
function(response)
{
//handle response
$(window).scrollTop(scroll);
});
```

Comment: this will work but it creates a flickering effect which is not good at all :)

Comment: This could work in order to capture their attempt to scroll and revert it:
   $(window).one('scroll.fbshare',function(){
      $(window).scrollTop(scroll);
   });

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is coming across this issue, just to reiterate [Jonathan Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12887/jonathan-tran)'s comment above about [this reported bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/359862544085722/), it has been fixed by Facebook, but only for the SHARE dialog. If you are still hitting this issue, you are probably calling the FEED dialog from your Javascript instead, which Facebook hasn't bothered to fix yet. Use this:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        ...
```

NOT this:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Improving the Nate idea...

```
    window['__sy'] = $(window).scrollTop();
    FB.ui(
    {
    //setup
    },
    function(response)
    {
    //handle response
    });
    $(window).one('scroll',function (){$(window).scrollTop(window['__sy'])});
```

Comment: You probably should explain how/why this is improving on Nate's answer. In general it's best if there is some explanation along with your code in answers.